# Fix for the message "The method empty() is undefined for the type JunitAssertions"

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5, hamcrest

I'm working with Junit Assertions. I'm facing problems when using assertThat. Below code shows that the 'assertThat' has been strike off.
Also whatever matcher i use like empty, is, equalsTo i get error message as 'The method empty() is undefined for the type JunitAssertions'.
The Junit version used in my project is 4.11.

My question is what needs to be done to use assertThat assertions ?.

Code copied from my project :

```
package BasicsOfJava.BasicsOfJava;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class JunitAssertions {

    @Test
    public void assertionsInJava()
    {   
           List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
            **assertThat**(emptyList, empty());
            Note : In my editor, assertThat is struck.      
                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`assertThat` are the assertion methods for [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/). JUnit decided to not support these assertions anymore because Hamcrest provides its own `assertThat` (see [PR 1150](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/pull/1150)). For you this means adding the import

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
```

and removing

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*
```

if you only use Hamcrest assertions. You also need to do a static import for the matchers like `empty()`. Basic matchers are in the class `CoreMatchers`

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This removed the error related to assertThat. Yet, am facing issues with the associated Matchers. I couldn't add static imports as there are no suggestions. When hovered, the message "The method empty() is undefined for the type JunitAssertions" is dispalyed. Also it suggests to create a method for empty().

Comment: Please read the [Hamcrest tutorial](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial) next time. The example has the fix: you have to add `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;` I fixed my answer accordingly.